# Firestore rules for permission

Tags: jquery, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Have 2 application using same firestore data.
1. **Frontend**
2. **Backend**

**Frontend**
using jquery to show data only.

**Backend**
Angular7 admin application, used to Create, Update, Delete Data for frontend.

now frontend prompt error

> Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

**Firestore Rules**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Code**

```
var dbRef = firebase.database();
var contactsRef = dbRef.ref("Slides");

//load older conatcts as well as any newly added one...
contactsRef.on("child_added", function(snap) {
  console.log("added", snap.key(), snap.val());
  $("#contacts").append(contactHtmlFromObject(snap.val()));
});
function contactHtmlFromObject(contact) {
  console.log(contact);
  var html = "";
  html += '<li class="list-group-item contact">';
  html += "<div>";
  html += '<p class="lead">' + contact.name + "</p>";

  html += "</div>";
  html += "</li>";
  return html;
}
```

Comment: Can you write the firestore request that you are trying to execute?

Comment: update question.

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of databases in Firebase: **Realtime Database** and **Firestore**.

Your request is accessing the **Realtime database**:

```
var dbRef = firebase.database();
var contactsRef = dbRef.ref("Slides");
```

but the rules are for your **Firestore** database:

```
service cloud.firestore {
```

So, you need to go to the Database section in Firebase and next to the title you will see a dropdown list. Switch to Realtime Databse and then select the `Rules` tab.

It should look like this:

```
{
    "Slides": {
      ".write": "auth != null",
      ".read": true,
    },
}
```